# Show a group with the transpositions

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

Show that $S_4=\langle{(12),(1234)}\rangle$.

These are the transpositions.

should I start with all the groups of $S_4$ ,  $S_4=4!$

And go about in proving the cosets of $S_4$?

Comment: Have you proven that all the transpositions generate the set $S_4$?

Comment: This is *not* the set of transpositions in $S_4$. The second element is not a transposition, and there are other transpositions that are not contained in your proposed generating set.

Comment: @miguel barnes: I think you are confused on the terminology and the problem. A transposition is an element of the form $(ij)$ (meaning a $2$ cycle). Read my answer to see if that clear things up a bit.

Answer (score 1):

What the problem is asking you is that using only $(12)$ and $(1234)$ show that you can obtain any element in $S_4$. One can show that if you have all the transpositions ($2$ cycles) then one has the entire group.

Ok, I am going to assume that you know that if you contain all the transpositions ($2$-cycles) then you have $S_n$. Call $H$ the subgroup generated by $(12)$ and $(1234)$

First: Since you have $(12)$ and $(1234)$, then you have:
$$
(23)=(1234)(12)(1234)^{-1}
$$
Hence, $(23)\in H$ 
$$
(34)=(1234)(23)(1234)^{-1}
$$Hence $(34)\in H$.
$$
(13)=(12)(23)(12)
$$Hence $(13)\in H$. 
$$
(14)=(13)(34)(13)
$$Hence $(14)\in H$.
$$
(24)=(12)(14)(12)
$$Hence, $(24)\in H$.

Thus, $H$ contains all $\binom{4}{2}=6$ transpositions. Can you now prove that it contains every element using all the transpositions.

Answer (score 0):

There are various semi-advanced ways to answer this question, but I think that the aim of this particular one is to just compute. Take the two elements you are given and start making a list of the elements they generate. After a while you'll get all the elements in $S_4$. Various tricks will shorten this process, but even with no tricks, you'll gain experience computing with permutations and you'll answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Idea is to "Quickly" compute the no of elements in $H=\big<(12),(1234)\big>$

$(1234)$ is of order $4$ so this will give me $3$ non identity elements

$(12)$ is of order $2$ so this will give me $1$ non identity element

$(12)(1234)=(234)$

please convince yourself (quickly :P) that $(234)\notin \big<(1234)\big>$ and $(234)\notin \big<(12)\big>$

So, this would give me again $2$ non identity elements

$(1234)(12)=(134)$

This would again give me $2$ non identity elements

Totally i have $8$ non identity elements

Including identity element it has $9$ elements

By thanking Lagrange theorem, we see that either $H=A_4$ or $H=S_4$

But, you please see that $(1234)\notin A_4$. Thus, $H=S_4$